# web2py: detect change in dropdown widget

Tags: python, jquery, web2py

How can we detect a change from a dropdown widget so that code can be executed?

Table `loan` references table `services`. Both have field called `interest_rate`. When I change `loan.service` via dropdown I'd like to reflect the corresponding `interest_rate` from `services` table to `loan` table.

How can this be achieved?

## model

```
db.define_table('services',
                Field('service_name',requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY(),IS_NOT_IN_DB(db,'services.service_name')]),
                Field('service_type','reference service_types',requires=IS_IN_DB(db,db.service_types.id,
                                                                                '%(type_name)s',
                                                                                error_message='not in table',
                                                                                zero=None),
                                                                                ondelete='RESTRICT',
                                                                                ),
                Field('interest_rate','decimal(15,2)',requires=IS_DECIMAL_IN_RANGE(0,100)),
                Field('max_term','integer'),
                auth.signature,
                format='%(service_name)s',
    )

db.define_table('loan',
    Field('service','reference services',requires=IS_IN_DB(db,db.services.id,
                                            '%(service_name)s',
                                            error_message='not in table',
                                            zero=None),
                                            ondelete='RESTRICT',),
    Field('member_id','reference members',requires=IS_IN_DB(db,db.members.id,
                                            '%(member_name)s',
                                            error_message='not in table',
                                            zero=None),
                                            ondelete='RESTRICT',
                                            label='Member'),
    Field('amount','decimal(15,2)',requires=IS_DECIMAL_IN_RANGE(1000)),
    Field('interest_rate','decimal(6,2)',default=10),
    )
```

Comment: I think change detection should be performed at front-end. Your interaction is being done with front-end, then your front-end code should refer to your back-end with a payload and reply with changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The material process is to monitor onchange with the `change()` event, something like this:

```
<script src="{{=URL('static', 'js/utils.js')}}"></script>
<script>

{{=ASSIGNJS(jslast_nos = last_nos)}}
{{=ASSIGNJS(jsaction = action)}}
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if (jsaction == "new") {
        jQuery("#AAP_doc_number").val(jslast_nos[jQuery("#AAP_pos_id").val()]);
    };
    jQuery("#AAP_pos_id").change(function(){
        pos_id = jQuery('#AAP_pos_id').val();
        jQuery("#AAP_doc_number").val(jslast_nos[pos_id]);
    });
    jQuery('#AAP_bags').change(function(){
        jQuery("#AAP_net_kg_qty").val(Number(jQuery('#AAP_bags').val() * 50));
        jQuery('#AAP_net_kg_qty').change();
    });
    jQuery('#AAP_net_kg_qty, #AAP_selling_price').change(function(){
        n = Number(jQuery('#AAP_net_kg_qty').val()) * Number(jQuery('#AAP_selling_price').val())
        jQuery('#AAP_amount').val(evenRound(Number(n),2).toFixed(2))
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using javascript in the front end. For example, using jquery library:

```
$("select").on("change", function(){

    var selected = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/get_rates",
        data:{
            "selected": selected
        },
        success: function(value_from_url){
            $("div").text(value_from_url);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This answer is nice, except that it relies on Ajax.